# Do all my screenshots need to be in English?

Tags: support

By answering a question on GD.SE yesterday i encountered the following problem:

Since i am german, i'm using all the CC Apps in german language. Therefore all the screenshots i make are german aswell. I really don't want to install the whole CC additionally in english just to make the screenshots for SE. Also i think that in 99% of the cases, everyone will recognize the visuals by their looks.

Will my posts be acceppted with screenshots that show CC Apps in german language?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad english :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Screenshots certainly aren't required for your answers so I considered them an added bonus. A German screenshot will have more value than no screenshot at all.

The only thing I would look out for is when transcribing steps, the menu items should be in English (e.g. use <kbd>File > New...</kbd> instead of <kbd>Datei > Neu...</kbd>). I understand that installing the English version of CC would be a major hassle, so please feel free to ask me or anyone else in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) if you need help translating the menus to English!

Answer (score 7):

I think a screenshot in a different language is better than no screenshot at all, but most users that come to the site looking for how-tos might not be familiar with the software. I imagine for them reading screenshots could be a challenge.

All materials except for samples are in English to avoid this kind of problems.

However, these are the solutions I propose:

- If the answer doesn't require very specific steps (finding some obscure command hidden under layers of navigation), and the visuals are clear, then a screenshot in German would be ok.
- If the text is important, you can either add the translation underneath it, or upload the screenshot in your language and someone else can edit in one in English.

Having said that, and from personal experience, I find it easier to run all my programs in English. When looking for solutions or trying to explain things to other, I realized I was spending too much time finding the matches (which are not always as intuitive as one may think).